# Design an automaton that accept the the set of strings $a$'s and $b$'s of length at least $2$

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Design an automaton that accept the the set of strings of $a$'s and $b$'s of length at least $2$, for which the final two symbols are different.

[image: DFA]

Comment: Your DFA doesn’t appear to have anything to do with the question, since its input language is $\{0,1\}$, not $\{a,b\}$. Moreover, it accepts that string $1$, which certainly is not of length at least $2$.

Comment: Posting an irrelevant DFA does not constitute an attempt. You need to show some relevant effort or explain the difficulty you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint:

Designing the DFA is a creative process, you need to experiment and verify.

The DFA has to accept strings of the form $(a|b)^* (ab|ba)$.

First try to design a DFA to accept $(ab|ba)$. This should give something
like (excuse crude diagram):

[image]

Now try to fill in the other links in the graph (that is, in any of the states, draw an arrow for the unrepresented input), and check that the
resulting DFA is correct.